# write access violation when inserting array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am defining a structer for my class. Basicly i want take an input and write it to member variable(array).

```
class DynArray
{

    int m_size;
    int* m_p_array;

public:
    DynArray(){
        std::cout << "Please enter size\n";
        std::cin >> m_size;
        m_p_array[m_size];
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < m_size; i += 1) {
            std::cout << "Please enter element " << i << "\n";
            std::cin >> m_p_array[i];   //"Exception thrown" message shows in this line
        }
    }
}
```

VS2019 shows me as a warning code :
C26495 Variable 'DynArray::m_p_array' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable

I just searched like 1 hour but didn't figgure out the what is my mistake. Is pointer i used for "m_p_array" problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a memory allocator for your array - new/delete or some other safer method.  Also, rule of 3 or 5 or others apply as this is in the constructor.

Comment: What do you think `m_p_array[m_size];` is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you allocate memory for the array:

```
m_p_array[m_size];
```

You need to do this:

```
m_p_array = new int[m_size];
```

later you need to free the memory in your destructor:

```
delete[] m_p_array;
```

but consider using `std::vector` instead because it is better.

Comment: [Documentation for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: A brief note on what `m_p_array[m_size];` actually did and how it contributed to the access violation would be educational for the questioner.

Comment: @user4581301 it didn't. `std::cin >> m_p_array[i];` did. The title clearly states "Write access violation"

Comment: It did. There is absolutely nothing wrong with `std::cin >> m_p_array[i];`. bhristov has pinpointed where the the bug was. The fact that the bug manifested viable effects a few lines later is irrelevant. I'm just prompting for a better explanation of what went wrong and why.

Answer (score 3):

A dynamic array in c++ is allocated with the `new` keyword like this:

```
m_p_array = new int[m_size];
```

Don't forget to delete this memory, usually in the destructor. You should also implement the special member functions correctly. Here's a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for how to approach this.

Note that:

```
m_p_array[m_size];
```

is simply indexing into the array, and doesn't declare or initialize anything.

Since you've never initialized `m_p_array`, you are accessing memory out of bounds, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: but std::vector is much much better

Comment: @pm100 of course, but OP is writing a class called `DynArray`, so I assume they are *implementing* `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

> didn't figgure out the what is my mistake

The mistake is there in the warning message:

> Variable 'DynArray::m_p_array' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable

Here:

> ```
> std::cin >> m_p_array[i];
> ```

You indirect through the uninitialised pointer, and attempt to assign the sibling of pointed object, which results in undefined behaviour.

You can solve this by initialising the member variables. You can do this either using a default member initialiser, or by using the member initialisation list.

> Basicly i want take an input and write it to member variable(array).

Actually, the member variable is not an array. It is a pointer. Perhaps this is the source of your problem. Maybe you should use an array member instead.